# Category of Trees To Model Hierarhcical Databases

Tags: category-theory

There are many ways to define Trees as a category. Is there any work on using category theory to represent hierarchical databases as trees? The goal is to be able to create functors between Hierarchical DBMS with Relational DBMS to integrate legacy databases.

Comment: Can you briefly describe what the target category would be?

Comment: I want to represent a simple database stored in a directory of various levels with the data files as the leaves at the bottom. I want this to be my object. Not quite sure what the morphism would be. If this can be turned into a category, then construct a functor to map this into a category of relational databases which D. Spivak has defined. If this can be done, then one can use the relational searches on the trees.